# Cant remove entire draggable

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I have an img element that is both draggable and resizeable.  I am trying to create a delete button for this element.  the delete button is embeded in the draggable container.  When I do

`$('deleteBtn').parent().remove();`

everything goes except the original image.  What am i doing wrong.

http://jsfiddle.net/p9PBA/2/

click the image to create the draggable, then the top left black box is the delete.

Edit: Is it possible this has something to do with the static positioning of the img element?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems to work:

```
deleteBtn.click(function(){
    $(this).siblings('img').remove();
    $(this).parent().remove();
});
```

Comment: Awesome, thanks.  Any idea why remove was missing the img? I tried empty before the remove and that didn't work either.

Comment: To tell you the truth, no. jQuery-ui must be doing something to the `div` it wraps around the image when you call `resizable()`. If you replace `$('.speechBub').resizable({ handles: "ne"}).parent().draggable({start: function(event, ui) { $(this).css("z-index", a++); }` with `$('.speechBub').wrap('<div />'); $('.speechBub').draggable({start: function(event, ui) {$(this).css("z-index", a++); }`, clicking the delete button will delete all contents of the wrapping div.